# Not able to select value from dropdown

Tags: eclipse, selenium, drop-down-menu, automated-tests

I have a dropdown menu for the select country. When I click on that dropdown it is open one search box and country list. We can select a country by searching a keyword in the search box. But I can't able to select country 'India'.

```
WebElement ctry = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-billing_country-container"));
ctry.click();
System.out.println("click on country successfully");
//Error starts from here..
Select country = new Select(ctry);
country.selectByVisibleText("India");

// Html code
// ctry Textbox 
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-billing_country-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="India">India</span>

// Search box
<input class="select2-search__field" type="text" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="select2-billing_country-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-billing_country-result-k084-IS">

// Specific country india code
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-billing_country-result-gulv-IN" role="option" data-selected="true" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true">India</li>

org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException:Element should have been "select" but was "span"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dropdown is not of the `Select` type, you cannot use the `Select` method on this dropdown. You need to click on the element using its xpath.
You can do it like:

```
WebElement ctry = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-billing_country-container"));
ctry.click();
System.out.println("click on country successfully");
WebElement country = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='India']"));
country.click();
```